# I'm trying to replace an image with a square (div shape) in this carousel

Tags: html, css

Using this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/1022/

I'm trying to insert the green square (currently below the carousel) into the carousel. Whenever I try to replace one of the images with the square's script, however, the other items in the carousel end up a line below. I believe it has something to do with the `.imageDiv img {` portion of the CSS script, but I'm not sure how to modify that. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

<div id="alternatewrapper" class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrolls">
   <img style="width:80px;" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
```

```
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    background:transparent;
    margin: auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.scrolls { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100px;
white-space:nowrap
} 
.imageDiv img { 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999; 
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
*zoom:1;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: DIV elements by default are block elements, so they would always take up the entire space on that line. Try changing it to `display: inline-block` and see if that keeps it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ".imageDiv img" portion of the CSS has nothing to do with it. Take the div you are trying to insert and do the following:

1) Add *display:inline-block;* right after *background-color:green;*

2) Cut/paste the div tag right after the first img tag (the 80px one)

You will now see the 80px green div right after the 80px placeholder image.

Please note that this is just a quick fix. I don't think you should be using so much inline CSS and I hope that you create a class that formats the DIVs you wish to insert. Good luck!

Comment: Follow-up: when I try to add text to the green square, it changes shape. I imagine it has something to do with the way the wrapping is set in CSS, but I can't seem to correct it: http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/1026/

Comment: That happens because of the way that inline elements are positioned (vertically) relative to an image. I'm sure you have noticed the effect when you try to type text next to an image in HTML. Solution: Replace all of the IMG tags with DIV tags. Isn't that what you want in the long run? If you want a mix of DIVs and IMGs, then you will need this in the CSS: *.scrolls img {vertical-align:top;}*

Comment: I would but I don't know how haha

Comment: Well, that was easy enough. Thanks :)